# How to remove single backslashe from string in php

Tags: php, string, backslash

I am trying to remove single backslash from string

```
$str = "Lionel Messi\'s is a footballer of the year.";
$str = stripslashes($str);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: I am voting to close as this is not reproducible. PHP 5.4 yields `Lionel Messi's is a footballer of the year.` with _echo $str_, as is expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to do that.

```
<?php 
  $str = "Hello world\'s";
  echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> str_replace('/', '', $str)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $string);
```